# Google algorithm for text on broken lines

Tags: c#, algorithm, google-maps

I wonder what kind of algorithm `Google` uses to show up text (like streets/rivers names etc.) on the map? Especially I want to know how they render the strings that they are folded (e.g. `N Cahuenga Blvd`).

I tried to have a look at `Google API`, but I couldn't find anything useful... :(

[image: Example]

Comment: Simple way would to render each glyph along the needed line, at the angle of that line.

Comment: Not that simple, because: 1. letter could have 10px and 10px is equal to 5 segments (2px each); 2. letters shouldn't overlap each other. I have large layers to convert with thousands of strings, that's why I need a fast algorithm:( couldn't find anything:/

Comment: Haven't understood your point 1, can you clarify a bit? About point 2 - the valid solution would be to check overlaps with previous glyph (or glpyhs, if your lines self-intersect), and if it does intersect, move it a bit (1px) to the right, check again, until there are no intersections.

Comment: Ad. 1. When you have a line (whole line 100px) and it's a broken line. Each segment (subline) is 2px long. Then your line consists of 50 pieces (2px each). And font size is 20px, then you will need to analyze 10 segments and draw a letter somewhere. Btw. your solution for 2. is a little costly, but I can use trygometry to solve this, no problem with overlapping, I only wonder how to place letters on line as fast as it's possible (for large layers that I need to process)... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guess (I have no idea what algorithm they use):

I would draw the streets using a curve that passes through all the corner points of what you call the "broken line". Specifically, I would try using a [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve) (a parametric curve that has useful properties for graphics, such as simple and fast calculation using integer arithmetic and nice results). For laying out the text, I would do something to make sure the text flows along the curve - for example as described [here](http://www.planetclegg.com/projects/WarpingTextToSplines.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely at Google maps on curvy roads, you will see places where letters touch, and where each letter seems to have a different slope.

Their system might be as conceptually simple as drawing 2 curves parallel to the center of the road - spaced one standard glyph height apart.  Then if the line is curving towards the top of the letters, space the next letter by measuring one letter width against the top line. If it curves the downward then use the lower line.  Draw each letter normal to the line at the resulting point.